# Apply gaussian filter on text

Tags: matlab, text, filter, gaussian

I'm trying to window a letter in a gaussian contrast envelope (so that the center of the letter is black and it has a smooth falloff around the edges) I've written a gaussian filter  with the size of the letter and I'm using text() function to draw the letter. I don't know how to apply the filter to a text. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show the code you are referring to? Maybe use `getframe` along with `imfilter`

Comment: If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox you can add text directly to an image with the [TextInserter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.textinserter-class.html) object. This also has nice edges already.

Comment: sigma = 6;
size = 18;
x = linspace(-size / 2, size / 2, size);
gaussFilter = exp(-x .^ 2 / (2 * sigma ^ 2));
gaussFilter = gaussFilter / sum (gaussFilter);

text1=text(0.5,0.5,'T','FontSize',18);

filt1 = filter (gaussFilter,1, text1);
 
I think the last 2 lines are not the correct way to go.
How do I show my text with a filter applied on it?

Comment: Try this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31409-render-text-to-image